# If statement inside a For loop - (If null don't add)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on a project with Firestore, I'm gathering Button data to create each button with a For loop. I could manage to get this data and store it to a List and create the buttons. Now I'm attempting to let the User Add or Delete his own buttons inside the App. 

 **This is an Example**
If I have 5 buttons in my App, I'm gathering info from firestore to know if these buttons are OFF or ON. I'm storing this bool states into a List, so if I have 5 buttons, I would have a list that you be:

```
List<bool> cardsValue = [false, false, true, false, true];
```

But when I delete one of these buttons, so Let's say I deleted the middle one, I would get an array, like this:

```
List<bool> cardsValue = [false, false, null, false, true];
```

I would need to Add an If statement so when I receive null as response, It won't add that null into my List. So my list would be:

```
List<bool> cardsValue = [false, false, false, true];
```

**End of example**
**Actual code:**

This is how my List actually looks:

```
List<bool> cardsValue = [for (int i = 0; i < cardamount; i++) snapshot.data[devices[i]]];
```

What I though on doing but unfortunatly didn`t work was:

```
List<bool> cardsValue = [for (int i = 0; i < cardamount; i++) if (snapshot.data[devices[i]] == null){}else{snapshot.data[devices[i]]}];
```

Comment: How do you delete your button and set Null in `cardValues`, add the code? Why not just remove the null and that entry? And if you're willing to go for an indicator of deleted button as `null` in this case then why not go for a List<String> instread of bool and put `Deleted` where ever the button was deleted? If you want to use null, this would work even better and further, you can customize the values as your liking like hidden/invisible, deleted, visible. You can also put the button text/position in this list using a regex.

Comment: It is because, I have Buttons states, For each device I have 1 field that stores that device true or false state. When I create the buttons in flutter, I'm using a for loop, So if I delete an Button that is on the middle, that will return null

Comment: @pskink Could you format the answer better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where` method of `List` class to filter out `null` values

```dart
List<bool> cardsValue = [for (int i = 0; i < cardamount; i++) snapshot.data[devices[i]]]
    .where((v) => v != null)
    .toList()
    .cast<bool>()
```

**Output**

```
[false, false, false, true]
```

Comment: When the `where` function runs, it passes all the values of the array to the function as argument & expects the function to return a `bool` value to decide whether to include the value or not.

Comment: Getting: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>'

Comment: Just add `as List<bool>` at the end

Comment: Workde fine too! thks

Comment: It is still giving me The list<dynamic> erro

Comment: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<bool>' in type cast

Answer (score 2):

Your initial approach was close, but Dart's collection-for and collection-if constructs cannot use braces; they must be used with *expressions*, not statements.

```dart
List<bool> cardsValue = [
  for (int i = 0; i < cardamount; i++)
    if (snapshot.data[devices[i]] != null)
      snapshot.data[devices[i]]
];
```